# ESLint "code" vs "whitespace" values for fixable

Tags: javascript, testing, abstract-syntax-tree, eslint, static-code-analysis

When a [rule is defined to be fixable](http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules#rule-basics), `fixable` key should be specified which can have `code` or `whitespace` values:

> `fixable` (string) is either "code" or "whitespace" if the `--fix` option on the command line automatically fixes problems reported by the rule

What are the differences between these values and what `whitespace` is for specifically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently ESLint doesn't use those values for anything (other then existence of any value under `fixable` property). This is meant for future use. For example, at some point ESLint might provide a way to only fix whitespace rules, or only code.
Currently "whitespace" should be used for any rule that deal with spacing (indentation, spacing between properties, etc.), everything else is marked as "code".